# I have an error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to compile my code but I keep getting an error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'. I don't know how to fix it.

I have tried changing the variable and code etc. I have a error at line 11, I am using codeskulptor online compiler.

```
a = float(input("Enter side A: "))

b = float(input("Enter side B: "))

c = float(input("Enter side C: "))

d = float(input("Enter side D: "))

e = float(input("Enter side E: "))

rect = (str(a*b))

sqaureleftside = (a - c)

sqaurerightside = (str(sqaureleftside - 0))

sqaure = (sqaureleftside ** 2)

trianglelegs = (str(e *sqaurerightside))

triangle = (str(trianglelegs/ 0.5))

totalarea = (rect + square + triangle)

print("Room Area: " + totalarea)
```

We have an abnormal shape, have to find the area. When inputing you should put:

```
Enter side A: 11

Enter side B: 2

Enter side C: 4

Enter side D: 7

Enter side E: 1

Answer:

Room Area: 53.5
```

Comment: When you convert `trianglelegs` to a `str`, you can't do arithmetic operations on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unnecessarily converted your computations to strings. Here's the cleaned up version:

```py
a = float(input("Enter side A: "))

b = float(input("Enter side B: "))

c = float(input("Enter side C: "))

d = float(input("Enter side D: "))

e = float(input("Enter side E: "))

rect = a * b

sqaureleftside = a - c

sqaurerightside = sqaureleftside - 0

square = sqaureleftside ** 2

trianglelegs = e * sqaurerightside

triangle = trianglelegs / 0.5

totalarea = rect + square + triangle

print("Room Area: " + str(totalarea))
```